# How to use generic types in abstract class

Tags: c#, inheritance

I'm trying to write a base class with some methods I want they are implemented in the classes that they inherit from this class.

In this example:

```
abstract public class ServiceBase 
{
    public ServiceBase()
    {
    }

    abstract public T Read<T>(string id);
    abstract public T Create<T>(T record);
    abstract public void Delete<T>(T record);
}

public class ServiceA: ServiceBase
{
    public Service(){}

    public override classA Read<classA>(string id)
    {
        ...
    }
    public override classA Create<classA>(classA record)
    {
        ...
    }
    public override void Delete<classA>(classA record)
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class ServiceB: ServiceBase
{
    public Service(){}

    public override classB Read<classB>(string id)
    {
        ...
    }
    public override classB Create<classB>(classB record)
    {
        ...
    }
    public override void Delete<classB>(classB record)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

this show the next error: "*no suitable method found to override*"

Is it possible to make this correct? How?

Comment: You misunderstand generics. If `ServiceBase` defines a method `Delete` which can delete any type of record, subclasses can't further constrain this: someone could always do `ServiceBase c = new ServiceA(); c.Delete<WhateverTheyWant>(x)`. It looks like you might want to make `ServiceBase` itself generic, i.e. `class ServiceBase<T> { public abstract void Delete(T record); ... }`, then specialise it in subclasses, e.g. `class ServiceA : ServiceBase<ClassA> { public override void Delete(Class A record) { } ... }`?

Comment: Is there _any_ relation between `serviceA` and `classA` for example, other that one uses the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the type `T` as part of your abstract class, and then pass a concrete type in your implementing class.

```
abstract public class ServiceBase<T> 
{
    public ServiceBase()
    {
    }

    abstract public T Read(string id);
    abstract public T Create<T>(T record);
    abstract public void Delete<T>(T record);
}
```

And then implementing, pass your type (in your example, either `classA` or `classB`) as such:

```
public class ServiceB: ServiceBase<classB>
{
    public Service(){}

    public override classB Read(string id)
    {
        ...
    }
    public override classB Create<classB>(classB record)
    {
        ...
    }
    public override void Delete<classB>(classB record)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you forgot to remove the generic type parameter from the methods e.g. `Read` rather than `Read<T>`. I suggest testing your code before posting it

Comment: It was copied from the original question with the additions, I'll adjust it now for accuracy but no need to be rude :)

Comment: (You've fixed `Read`, but what about the others?)

Comment: This line `abstract public T Create<T>(T record);`  is absolutely not the same as `abstract public T Create(T record);` meaning when you write `...<T>(T record)` it means that the parameter of this method must be of type `<T>`  which can be a different `T` defined in the class. You could have written the same like this: `abstract public T Create<U>(U record) where U:ClassB` for example. So canton7 is right you should write the method as he said.

Comment: I have a new problem. I've fixed my code as you say, but I have an error with the types conversion. ClassA and ClassB are in other project of my solution. This project are referenced in the using list. But visual studio shows the next error in each overrided methods: "cannot convert from 'ClassA' to 'Models.Database.ClassA'"

Comment: Lack of precision in your comment JulioC ! Maybe you didn't specify the return object in each overriden method, e.g: `return (T) obj;` where `obj` is the value to be returned. Or maybe it is a matter of type referencing. Check the namespace and the class name case because C#'s types are case sensitive, meaning `classB` and `ClassB` are not the same.

Comment: `public class ServiceConcrete2 : ServiceBase<ClassB>
{
 public override ClassB Read(string id)
 {
  object o = new object();
                **return (ClassB)o;**
 }
 public override ClassB Create(ClassB record)
 {
  object o = new object();
  **return (ClassB)o;**
 }
 public override void Delete(ClassB record)
 {
  
 }
}`

Comment: Yes, this change is good. The problem was the type "<classB or A>" after method name.

Comment: Right, the thing I said needed to be changed a couple of hours ago.

Comment: It is best practice to mark the constructor of an abstract type `protected`. As in `protected ServiceBase() { }`

Answer (score 2):

```
public class ClassA { }

public class ClassB { }

abstract public class ServiceBase<T> where T : class
{
    abstract public T Read(string id);
    abstract public T Create(T record);
    abstract public void Delete(T record);
}

public class ServiceConcrete1 : ServiceBase<ClassA> 
{
    public override ClassA Read(string id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override ClassA Create(ClassA record)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override void Delete(ClassA record)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class ServiceConcrete2 : ServiceBase<ClassB>
{
    public override ClassB Read(string id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override ClassB Create(ClassB record)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override void Delete(ClassB record)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the accepted @jayGould answer, but with some additional tidbits to make it more inline with best practices.

I assume the target class for the service methods all have some commonality between them, and so it is useful to constrain `ServiceBase<T>` to use this common ancestor:

```
public interface IClass { }

public class ClassA  : IClass { }
public class ClassB  : IClass { }

abstract public class ServiceBase<T> where T:IClass
{
    protected ServiceBase() { }

    abstract public T Read(string id);
    abstract public T Create(T record);
    abstract public void Delete(T record);
}

public class ServiceA : ServiceBase<ClassA>
{
    public ServiceA() : base() { }

    public override ClassA Read(string id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override ClassA Create(ClassA record)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override void Delete(ClassA record)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class ServiceB : ServiceBase<ClassB>
{
    public ServiceB() : base() { }

    public override ClassB Read(string id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override ClassB Create(ClassB record)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override void Delete(ClassB record)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Additionally, an `abstract` class should only have `protected` constructors since they can only be called from derived classes.